# Why is the Hubble law so accurate at scales smaller than galactic voids?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, galaxy-clusters

It's possible to derive the Hubble law:
$$v = H_0 d$$
from the FRW metric by differentiation.

Experimentally the Hubble law appears to hold for relatively small distances, say 20 Mpc and smaller. However the FRW metric assumes homogeneity and isotropy which at present times is not accurate on scales smaller than $\sim$100 Mpc.

Why then does the Hubble law still appear to hold to some degree of accuracy at scales smaller than the cosmic voids - i.e. where homogeneity is not seen?

Comment: According to what experiments?

Comment: @JohnDoty the observations that suggested the law to begin with for example

Comment: You should look for later, more accurate work. Hubble's observations were suggestive, but not really quantitative.

Comment: Hubble's distance estimates were far too low.

Comment: Are you sure Hubble's law appears to hold at 20 Mpc? See e.g. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/found-the-fastest-approaching-object-in-the-universe/ which is an object that shows a strong blueshift in spite of being >16 Mpc away.

Comment: @JohnDoty Yeah, maybe you're right. Looking again at the data, there is quite a spread in the velocities below 100 Mpc with only a vague linear trend. I suppose this comes from the Hubble speeds being low or comparable to peculiar velocities at small distances.

Comment: @Kris Riess 2009 also uses $0.023<z<0.1$ for Hubble measurements, where $z=0.023$ corresponds to $\sim 100\rm{Mpc}$. As you have said, peculiar velocities and gravitational effects will impact the observation of the recession velocity.

Comment: The global metric relates to the large scale uniformity. The local metric may be slightly off, but not too much, due to the local non-uniformities. You question effectively assumes that the local physics is defined by the local distribution of matter, but this premise is incorrect. In a large river, the local current is mostly defined by the global flow and is only slightly affected by the local obstacles. Similarly the local Hubble law is defined by the global metric while local non-uniformities are responsible for peculiar velocities. Your question seems to be based on the wrong premise.